# What are some examples of non-homologous sequences having similar functions?

Tags: evolution, proteins, molecular-evolution, protein-evolution, homology

I am trying to find some proteins that are non-homologous but functionally similar. However, I cannot seem to find concrete examples. Can someone please point out any resources or provide examples?

Comment: Would something as broad as a gene involved in the development of wings in insects and one involved in the development of wings in birds be a satisfying answer?

Comment: Yea, sure, that would work.

Comment: By, homologous gene, do you mean gene with independent origin and similar function or independent origin and similar sequence?

Comment: I mean examples of sequences that are not similar(i.e. you cannot find them by BLASTing) but their functions are similar.

Answer (score 5):

#### Serine Protease Catalytic Triad

This is classic example of convergent evolution in catalytic mechanisms. Shown below are chymotrypsin ([4CHA](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=4cha), green) and subtilisin ([1ST2](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore/explore.do?structureId=1st2), blue) aligned on their catalytic triads (Ser/His/Asp, darker colours). There is no obvious sequence or structural similarity.

[image]

You can check out the [MEROPS database](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/merops/cgi-bin/clan_index?type=P#S) for a list of protease clans (*"represents one or more families that show evidence of their evolutionary relationship"*) and [this paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/8/E653.full) for a discussion on convergent evolution of the catalytic triad:

> Although the biophysics of rate acceleration are intricate and sensitive to even minor structural perturbations, evolution has converged on a catalytic triad (or diad) with a reactive Ser, Cys, or Thr nucleophile more than 25 separate times to facilitate central biochemical reactions such as hydrolysis, transacylation, and phosphorylation.

Answer (score 2):

*Hoxd12* and *Hoxd13* are involved in the development of wings in birds ([Vargas and Fallon 2004](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jez.b.21023/full)).

*pdm* and *aptorus* are involved in the development of wings in insects ([Williams et al. 1993](http://dev.biologists.org/content/develop/117/2/571.full.pdf), [Averof and Cohen 1997](https://search.proquest.com/docview/204464028?pq-origsite=gscholar))

Comment: Thanks. But, which of them are non-homologous?

Comment: *Hoxd12* and *Hoxd13* are of independent origin than *pdm* or *aptorus* but all are involved in the development of wings.